# Rolling restart of process group in monit

Tags: monitoring, restart, monit

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I might go about achieving a rolling restart of a process group using monit?

Thanks in advance,
fturtle

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure for which server you are talking about. But I can provide you an example for thin which supports rolling restart itself. (option `onebyone: true`)

So for monit you can use something like,

`if ... then exec '/path/to/thin_restart.sh'`

And `thin_restart.sh` would be something like,

```
source /path/to/scripts/rvm
rvm use your_gemset@some_ruby
thin -C thin.yml restart
```

And contents of thin.yml would look like,

```
port: 1337
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
rackup: /path/to/config.ru
daemonize: true
servers: 2
onebyone: true
```

There are other ways to fine tune this restarts based on pid. You can monitor files with pids and restart only those thin process based on conditions.

e.g.

```
check process app-1337
  with pid /path/to/app.1337.pid
  start = 'thin -d -p 1337 start'
  stop  = 'thin -d -p 1337 -P /path/to/thin.1337.pid stop'
  if cpu usage > 50% then restart
check process app-1338
  with pid /path/to/app.1338.pid
  start = 'thin -d -p 1338 start'
  stop  = 'thin -d -p 1338 -P /path/to/thin.1338.pid stop'
  if cpu usage > 50% then restart
```

The other way would be of using groups which monit provides.

Extending above example.

```
check process app-1337
  with pid /path/to/app.1337.pid
  group thin
  group thin-odd
  start = 'thin -d -p 1337 start'
  stop  = 'thin -d -p 1337 -P /path/to/thin.1337.pid stop'
  if cpu usage > 50% then restart
check process app-1338
  with pid /path/to/app.1338.pid
  group thin
  group thin-even
  start = 'thin -d -p 1338 start'
  stop  = 'thin -d -p 1338 -P /path/to/thin.1338.pid stop'
  if cpu usage > 50% then restart
check process app-1337
  with pid /path/to/app.1339.pid
  group thin
  group thin-odd
  start = 'thin -d -p 1339 start'
  stop  = 'thin -d -p 1339 -P /path/to/thin.1339.pid stop'
  if cpu usage > 50% then restart
check process app-1340
  with pid /path/to/app.1340.pid
  group thin
  group thin-even
  start = 'thin -d -p 1340 start'
  stop  = 'thin -d -p 1340 -P /path/to/thin.1340.pid stop'
  if cpu usage > 50% then restart
```

So now you can do following to restart all:

```
monit -g thin restart
```

or to achieve sort of rolling restart, restart odd ones then even.
To restart only odd ones:

```
monit -g thin-odd restart
```

and to restart even:

```
monit -g thin-even restart
```